# div that scroll at the bottom in Angular2

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass

Sorry for the bad title, I really have no idea on how to write something that has sense in few words.

the situation is like this:

[image]

The div that scroll has this css:

```
.element-list{
  width:100%;
  max-height: 180px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

the topBar has an `height` of `20px` and the main wrapper is of `200px`.

Inside the div that scroll, in the html, there is something like this (that's useless to you, but just for letting you understand better) :

```
<div class="something" *ngFor="let data of myData">
  <div>{{data.id}}</data>
</div>
```

This works fine, whenever I add something into `myData` is reflected into the ngFor so I see more and more `<div>{{data.id}}</data>`.

What I'm trying to achieve is to automatic scroll at the bottom whenever there are elements that trigger the `overflow-y: auto;`.

What I mean is: Since I have few elements(let's say, for example, ten elements), the scroll-bar is hidden. but when the elements are more than ten, the scroll bar appears, but it doesn't go to the bottom.

Like this:

[image]

As you can see there are more element. What I want, is that the div will auto-scroll to the bottom. So whenevener something is added it will always be like this:

[image]

Is there a way to do it in Angular or by scss/css?

Comment: you can surely hook into the data-added event and then use element.scrollIntoView()

Comment: Ya like, synoon says, I'd say just fire off a method if .length is greater than 3 or something that just does `document.getElementByClass('element-list').scrollIntoView(false);` or use elementref, whatever...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

call scrollBottom() after view completed using **ngAfterViewChecked**

[working sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mvp2rb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) - click add button UI to experiment

html

```
<div style="height:200px; overflow-y:auto;" #scroll>
    <div *ngFor="let i of list">
        {{i.name}}
        <br>
    </div>
</div>


<button (click)="Add()">Add</button>

<button (click)="scrollToTop()">Scroll to top</button>
<button (click)="scrollBottom()">Scroll to bottom</button>
```

component

```
@ViewChild('scroll', { read: ElementRef }) public scroll: ElementRef<any>;

  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    this.scrollBottom()
  }

  public scrollBottom() {
    console.log(this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop);
    this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop = this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollHeight;

  }

  public scrollToTop() {
    this.scroll.nativeElement.scrollTop = 0;
  }
```

Comment: Make sure you accept and upvote the answer if you feel its helpful

Comment: when i try to "say" that ElementRef is of type `any` it gives me the error that it can't be any, so I've deleted that `<any>` and it's not working

Comment: @JacopoSciampi  did you checked the sample I have provided?

Comment: Sure, but it says that "Element Ref is not generic"

Comment: did you use different version angular and angular material packages?

Comment: @angular/... are all 5.2.5 and I'm not using material

Comment: you can declare without any like @ViewChild('scroll', { read: ElementRef }) public scroll: ElementRef;

Comment: Eh, tried that but didn't work. I mean, it just didn't scroll

Comment: Is the code I shared is not working or the integration with your application is not working?

Comment: I just putted the viewChild with the code on the example and the #scroll on my div and didn't wor, do you wanna continue in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181079/discussion-between-pandiyan-cool-and-jacopo-sciampi).